# Rotating an inscribed square in Geogebra

Tags: geometry

I am trying to figure out how to rotate the inside square so that the sides lengthen based on the degree of rotation. For example, after rotating 90 degrees in either direction, it should precisely match the outside square.

Thank you.

[image: inscribed square][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8d4H.png)
![inscribed square]

Comment: The relevant commands are `Polygon[...]` , `Rotate[...]` , `Stretch[...]` , and `Translate[...]`

Answer (score 3):

I did this by creating an angle slider, $\alpha$, let it take any angle between 0 and 360. Through the center of the circle construct a line using the center as the vertex and the angle $\alpha$. Let this line be line $m$, now construct line $n$ perpendicular to line $n$ through the center. Use the point intersection tool and find the intersection of each line and the polygon (your square $ABCD$). Construct the polygon using these four intersection points. Now you can rotate the inside square and it will resize accordingly.

Here's my result.
[image: square-rotating]